# Should one say proclivity or proclivities?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Should "proclivity" be singular or plural?

> ...his depressive **proclivity** caused...

> ...his depressive **proclivities** caused...

Answer (score 2):

Both see some use.  Either is possible.  If you mean to indicate that his depression manifests itself in many different ways, you might prefer the plural.  Otherwise the singular is not incorrect and probably preferable.

Answer (score 1):

A proclivity is 'a tendency to choose or do **something** regularly' or 'an inclination or predisposition towards **a particular thing**' (Oxford Languages).

We might want to talk about a person's single tendency or inclination to do something, e.g. **a** proclivity for hard work, for exaggeration, to complain, or for music. These individual tendencies would be discussed using the singular noun. If a person had more than one tendency, we might talk about 'his (or her) proclivities' using the plural form of the noun, e.g. 'her proclivities for hard work and thoroughness made her a good team member'.

In Britain, I don't know about anywhere else, if someone has preferences for some (often sexual) activity or activities, which people do not wish to name, they might say e.g. 'He lost his job as a priest because of his proclivities'.